# Realm file size in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an app that uses Realm as a staging database.  It receives information from a bluetooth device, processes it, and sends the processed result to a server.

The incoming data from bluetooth gets stored in a Realm table (table1).  A separate thread reads data from the Realm database, processes it, and stores it into a second table (table2) for uploading to a server.  When it pulls this data and successfully processed it, it deletes it from table1.

The third thread pulls data from table2, and when it successfully sends, removes it from table2.

I'm using a database here in case, for whatever reason, the app is killed - data won't be lost... it will just resume where it left off when the app is restarted.  But as you can see, the database is not something that hangs around (it's not like an address book or something... it is just temporary staging)

What I notice is that no matter what the heck I do, the realm database *file* just increases in size over time.  I'll end up with a database that if I open it, will have one record in it, but the database file on disk could be 10s of MB in size if the app is running long enough.

Data is being processed on different background queues so as to not block any UX (one of the reasons I'm using Realm instead of CoreData).  But I'm using things like autoreleasepools and the invalidate command to avoid objects that are read from having copies made (as suggested by many realm questions/answers)

What gives?  I know I don't have a code sample here, but this just seems like a basic garbage collection problem in Realm.  I've seen other questions related to this where people are like "why is my database so huge", and the answers suggest doing things like "writeCopyToPath", but that feels like an incredible hack, and regardless, it would be very difficult - this app is meant to be constantly connected and monitoring a bluetooth device, so to do this, it would mean stopping, making sure all threads that might alter the database are quiesced, doing the copy to compact the db, and then starting everything back up again.  That just seems nonsensical to me.  I might interrupt user operations for example. I don't want a user to not be able to do something because I decided it was time to do database maintenance.

I feel like I'm either missing some incredibly fundamental point in how to make Realm not keep junk around, or Realm is just the completely wrong solution for my problem.  I've never seen this problem with databases - adding and deleting lots of records... quickly... seems like something a database should just be able to do without exploding in size.

Comment: Have you considered using the Realm Object Server (https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) to transfer the data to the backend? It seems like that would prevent you from needing to have multiple tables (as the data could just be extracted from the synchronized realm serverside).

Comment: that won't work for our application

Comment: deleted records leave empty space, which Realm supposedly does reclaim, but does not immediately shrink unless you explicitly call `Realm.compact()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known problem, see [this ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4353). We're working to address it; in the meantime you can try using `Realm.writeCopy()` or one of the other workarounds in that thread.

Comment: Yes, sadly that's what I had to do (the writeCopy). This is extremely painful because the data is written and read using independent threads, and not based upon user interaction (Bluetooth connections). But I think I did it.  Seriously, this is just terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that the background thread is not holding on to old versions of the Realm, preventing the space from being reused?

Quote from the docs (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads):

> If a thread has no runloop (which is generally the case in a background thread), then Realm.refresh() must be called manually in order to advance the transaction to the most recent state.
>
> Failing to refresh Realms on a regular basis could lead to some transaction versions becoming “pinned”, preventing Realm from reusing the disk space used by that version, leading to larger file sizes.

Comment: Yes, i do run refresh().  What I notice is this: let's say the thread going to the server is fast (a good cell connection).  Data goes into the tables and out of the tables at almost the same rate, and the file size does not increase.  If the cell connection is bad, data builds up (naturally), and then when the cell connection is good, the data is deleted, but the disk space is never reclaimed.  The record is deleted, but the disk space is not reclaimed.  So, over time, it just grows and grows.

Comment: That does seem to indicate either that `refresh()` is not being called, or that some old `Realm` objects are hanging around keeping old versions locked up. The moment you call `refresh()` the space used by all versions before the call can be reclaimed.

Comment: What I've done is two fold.  One, the thing that uploads from the database (a background thread) no longer deletes from the database.  It just updates the record as "processed" ( so that I don't try to upload it again ).  The main thread, which writes to the database, looks at processed records and deletes them there.  The second thing I do is whenever I think it's safe, I do a compaction (writeCopy).  that seems to address all the problems.  I think it is absolutely ridiculous that realm frees up space to try to re-use it, but never just gives it back.  That's just dumb.